# How to structure a large C++ project?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, gnu-make, automake

*Even though many have answered parts of the question in specific cases, I couldn't find a clear answer reflecting the community consensus on the best practices to use in the general case*

**How should I structure a big C++ project, containing many modules (shared libraries, executables, bindings) along with their documentation, builds, configuration, etc... ?**

As a bonus, it would be interesting to describe how the integration with the mainstream build systems like CMake or Autotools would looke like, based on real-life examples.

Please note it should target cross-platform, IDE-independant projects. Specific information for basic, widely-used libraries may also be a good addition, like Qt (QMake, Qt Creator) or Boost.

Comment: Well, that all depends on if you use source control, and what features that source control has.  Git submodules for example are nice to pull in 3rd party libs; but not all 3rd party libs are available on git.  I'd say this is way too broad, and even if it wasn't, it's based on personal preference.

Comment: Well, I think the site needs such a broad question. IMO, a good answer, wrapping-up all the things to take into account, would be welcome for a large majority of beginner C++ developpers. It is a very difficult step to take when switching from tutorials to real-life coding.

Comment: Ahh - well, I can wrap the issues into a single one really.  The main thing to take into account is your memory and logic - since you need to be able to traverse your files quickly to find file X in library Y.   How you think and remember things though is personal preference.  ;)

Comment: afaik there is no community consensus in the general case. Nevertheless a collection of pros and cons could be useful (and is not necessarily opinion-based)

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Large-Scale-C-Software-Design-APC/dp/0201633620

Comment: Every company I worked for did this in a different way :) ... in the fact the current company I'm working in does this in at least 3 different ways (I know of) right at this moment (although tries to migrate from the "old ways" to the most recent "new way")

Comment: @user463035818 You can't even list the pros and cons of things because it depends on other coding styles - for example The person who puts one class per header will likely have a different layout to one that has a strict single class / header because the pros of one layout don't apply for this case.  What about the one where there's multiple languages?  Or auto-generated code?  The only thing that you can be sure of is that there will be files; and there may be directories, but there's no requirement for that one either.